# TypeError in Node REPL: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when I add a property to the Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I added the `name` property to `Object.prototype` and reference `Object.prototype`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

But I can read `Object.prototype.name`. Is the `name` property something special for `Object.prototype`? Why does this error occur?

The code has been executed in Node v6.9.5 environment on Mac OS X. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
$ node
> Object.prototype
{}
> Object.prototype.value = 'foo';
'foo'
> Object.prototype.name = 'bar';
'bar'
> Object.prototype
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> Object.prototype.name
'bar'
> Object.prototype.value
'foo'
> delete Object.prototype.name
true
> Object.prototype
{ value: 'foo' }
> Object.prototype.name = 'bar';
'bar'
> Object.prototype
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> delete Object.prototype.value;
true
> Object.prototype
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.stylizeWithColor [as stylize] (util.js:242:43)
    at formatProperty (util.js:814:18)
    at util.js:654:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at formatObject (util.js:653:15)
    at formatValue (util.js:592:16)
    at Object.inspect (util.js:186:10)
    at REPLServer.self.writer (repl.js:468:19)
    at finish (repl.js:593:38)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:385:5)
```

Comment: other than saying: don't mess with Object.prototype, there isn't a good explanation for this. Object.prototype should not treat a property `name` differently, however `Function.name` does.

Comment: Weirdly enough, this seems specific to Node. Cannot reproduce on latest Chrome, but reproduced in Node v5.5.0 on WIndows.

Comment: What value it is showing you for JSON.stringify(Object.prototype) and Object. @Kouta Osabe  Can you check once?

Comment: I checked. the result as follows.
> JSON.stringify(Object.prototype);
'{"value":"foo","name":"bar"}'
@RahulPandey

Comment: I tried the same command on latest Chrome. as you tell me, i can not reproduce this problem on the Chrome. this is just Node's specification problem?  if it's so, i do not care about it. thx.
@AndrewLi

Answer (score 5):

After some inspection I found the culprit and yes, the problem is that `"name"` is used in a special way.

This error has nothing to do with JavaScript, it is a bug in the Node REPL code that styles the output.

Since we're printing an object, the code ends up executing [this function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L618):

```
function formatObject(ctx, value, recurseTimes, visibleKeys, keys) {
  return keys.map(function(key) {
    return formatProperty(ctx, value, recurseTimes, visibleKeys, key, false);
  });
}
```

Where `value` is our `Object.prototype`, i.e. `{ name: 'bar' }` and `keys` is an array of single element, i.e. `["name"]`.

For this single key `"name"`, execution continues to [`formatProperty`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L732), where it skips the checks to format objects with getters/setters or symbols and reaches a call to [`formatValue`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L267) on [this line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L758). This call returns a color-coded representation of the value we should print, in our case something like `"[32m'bar'[39m"`.

Next, the code tries to build a string to display the context being printed. This is the string corresponding to the type of the data being printed, for example `[Object]`, `[Getter]`, etc. The execution [reaches this call](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L778):

```
ctx.stylize(name, 'name');
```

The first argument `name` is our property `"name"` and the second argument `'name'` represents the type of the data we are printing, `'name'` meaning variable name.

Further, `stylize` is actually [`stylizeWithColor`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L204) since [`ctx.colors`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L150) is true by default.

The error happens in `stylizeWithColor` on [this line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L208).

```
function stylizeWithColor(str, styleType) {
  var style = inspect.styles[styleType];

  if (style) {
    return `\u001b[${inspect.colors[style][0]}m${str}` + // <- ERROR: `inspect.colors[style][0]` becomes `undefined[0]`
           `\u001b[${inspect.colors[style][1]}m`;
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
```

**But why?**

Well, the call to `stylizeWithColor` passes `'name'` as the `styleType`, but the only valid values for `styleType` are:

```
boolean
date
null
number
regexp
special
string
symbol
undefined
```

`'name'` style type is actually [ignored](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L195) as variable names are meant to be unstyled.

These style types are stored in a plain object [`inspect.styles`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L186) so the execution expects `inspect.styles['name']` on the first line to return `undefined` (since it is ignored) and not enter the `if` statement.

```
// ...

var style = inspect.styles[styleType]; // <-- this should return `undefined`

if (style) { // <-- this shouldn't happen

// ...
```

However, since `inspect.styles` is just a POJO and we added a `"name"` property on `Object.prototype`, `inspect.styles['name']` doesn't find `'name'` directly but does find it up the [[Prototype]] chain and actually returns `"bar"`.

```
// ...

var style = inspect.styles[styleType]; // <-- this returns "bar"` because it found it up the [[Prototype]] chain

if (style) { // <-- this happens because "bar" is truthy

// ...
```

This means that the code tries to execute `inspect.colors["bar"][0]`, where [`inspect.colors`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/193468667b84b416cd5c5a9f42bc34deedae858e/lib/util.js#L169) is another POJO containing a mapping of colors to their [escaped code values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) for printing in the terminal. As one would inspect,`"bar"` is not one of them.

Hence we get `undefined[0]`, which throws the error in question.

As a matter of fact, if you make `name` equal to a color value used in `inspect.colors`, then the error wouldn't happen and the property `name` will be printed in that color.

[image: node color print]

---

Edit: I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/11624) that fixes this problem by making `inspect.styles` a prototype-less object.

Edit 2: This has been fixed as of [Node 8](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/aab0d202f8edb079070f417ab4b35678ac937608)

Answer (score -1):

you should try this:

```
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object);
```

Comment: I tried this.

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object);
[ 'length',
  'name',
  'arguments',
  'caller',
  'prototype',
  'assign',
  'create',
  'freeze',
  'getOwnPropertyDescriptor',
  'getOwnPropertyNames',
  'getOwnPropertySymbols',
  'is',
  'isExtensible',
  'isFrozen',
  'isSealed',
  'keys',
  'preventExtensions',
  'seal',
  'defineProperty',
  'defineProperties',
  'getPrototypeOf',
  'setPrototypeOf' ]

Comment: also tried the same function for Object.prototype.
the result as follows.

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
[ 'hasOwnProperty',
  'constructor',
  'toString',
  'toLocaleString',
  'valueOf',
  'isPrototypeOf',
  'propertyIsEnumerable',
  '__defineGetter__',
  '__lookupGetter__',
  '__defineSetter__',
  '__lookupSetter__',
  '__proto__',
  'value',
  'name' ]